# error:no such partition fond grub rescue

Tags: dual-boot

Before I start you should know that I am completely new to ubuntu. I have windows 7 installed on my computer as well as ubuntu 9.10.

I recently deleted the ubuntu to make room on my computer for some HD movies that I was planning on burning. I am planning to reinstall ubuntu once I'm done with these movies.

Since uninstalling ubuntu i am no longer able to boot my windows 7 or do anything on my computer. Now when I try to start my computer the only message that I get is:

```
GRUB loading.
error: no such partition
grub rescue>
```

My computer is stuck at this point. I need help getting my computer working again. I want to keep the GRUB loader because I planning on reinstalling ubuntu. If anyone can help me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is because GRUB's files are on Ubuntu's partition. I don't know anything else then reinstalling Ubuntu or restoring the Windows bootloader using a Windows recovery DVD and putting GRUB back on later

Comment: I would suggest having a look here, It explains about how to download a live boot CD for GRUB and GRUB2 fix [http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/live-cd-to-fix-restore-grub-and-grub2.html (Live CD to Fix GRUB/GRUB2)

Comment: You have to repair windows and re-install the windows boot loader. http://blog.danielburrowes.com/2012/02/repair-windows-7-after-removing-linux.html

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I deleted a partition that I had installed ubuntu on. It wouldnt let me boot windows through my cd drive until I went to bios and changed it from fast boot to thorough boot. This allowed me to at least boot on my windows 7 disk. Dont know if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question is *very* common, especially in beginners (I did it myself once :D, so don't feel bad.) This happens when you manage to overwrite/delete the GRUB files.

These files are usually stored on the Ubuntu partition, so if you deleted the Ubuntu partition, you probably deleted those files too. If you have the Windows install disks you can just google `repair MBR from Windows install/repair disk`, or look at this http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/347632/fix-mbr-without-install-disk/ website and follow the instructions for your situation. The MBR (Master Boot Record) is how Windows boots itself up when the computer turns on, so it rather important.